# Uninstall specific version of mysql OSX

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite, uninstallation

I installed mysql using .dmg, and then I realized I already have mysql installed. Now I have two versions, and I would like to keep the one that was shipped with OSX.

Is there a way to do it and how?

Comment: No possibilty to use Timemaschine?

Comment: I'm new to OSX, just got my Mac yesterday, I'll check what Timemachine is, thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/887006/uninstall-specific-version-of-mysql-osx/887493#887493